# How to make two python programs interact?

Tags: python, multithreading, ipc, process, interaction

I have a HTTP sever in one program and my basic application in another one. Both of them are loops, so I have no idea how to:

1. Write a script that would start the app and then the HTTP server;
2. Make these programs exchange data in operation.

How are these things usually done? I would really appriciate Python solutions because my scripts are written in Python.

1. Does a user make an http request which queries the app for some data and return a result? **Yes**
2. Does the app collect data and store it somewhere? **The app and the HTTP Server both use SQLite database. However the DBs may be different.**

Comment: This is still pretty vague.  It would be good to provide the actual interactions between person and "system" and between the two programs that comprise this "system".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering, I think we need some more information:

1. Is there a definable pipeline of information here?

   1. Does a user make an http request which queries the app for some data and return a result?
   2. Does the app collect data and store it somewhere?

There are a few options depending on how you're actually using them. Sockets is an option or passing information via a file or a database.

**[Edit]** Based on your reply I think there's a few ways you can do it:

1. If you can access the app's database from the web server you could easily pull the information you're after from there. Again it depends what information it is that you want to exchange.
2. If your app just needs to give the http server some results, you could write them into a results table in the http server's db.
3. Use pipe's or sub processes as other people have suggested to exchange data with the background app directly.
4. Use a log file which your app can write to and your http server read from.

Some more questions:

1. Do you need two-way communication here or is the http server just displaying results?
2. What webserver are you using?
3. What processing languages do you have available on it?

Depending on how reliant the two parts can be, it might be best to write a new app to check the database of your app for changes (using hooks or polling or whatever) and post relevent information into the http server's own database. This has the advantage of leaving the two parts less closely coupled which is often a good thing.

I've got a webserver (Apache 2) which talks to a Django app using the fastcgi module. Have a look at [the section in djangobook on fastcgi](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12/). Apache uses sockets (or regular tcp) to talk to the background app (Django).

**[Edit 2]** Oops - just spotted that your webserver is a python process itself. If it's all python then you could [launch each in it's own thread](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) and pass them both [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) objects which allow the two processes to send each other information in either a blocking or non-blocking manner.

Answer (score 3):

a) You can start applications using **os.system**:

```
os.system("command")
```

or you can use the **subprocess** module. More information [here](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

b) use sockets

Comment: Thanks, do you mean TCP Sockets or some other sockets?

Comment: Are there other kinds of sockets?  I'm curious why you're asking, @Alex.

Comment: Not exactly.  IPC sockets are similar, but don't use the network stack.  See http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node28.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_sockets for details.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can probably just use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module.  For the exchanging data, you may just be able to use the Popen.stdin and Popen.stdout streams.  Of course, there's no limit to ways you /could/ do it.  [CORBA](http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/), [DBUS](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html), [shared memory](http://semanchuk.com/philip/sysv_ipc/), [DCOP](http://www.kdedevelopers.org/node/124), the list goes on.  But try the simple way first, which in this case is regular python pipes/streams.

Comment: I don't see how you question update helped explain what you're doing.  Presumably, you don't want to use the db for message passing.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do you can use os.mkfifo to create a named pipe to share data between your two programs.

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-August/568346.html

Answer (score 1):

maybe [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

When I write web applications in Python, I always keep my web server in the same process as my background tasks.  I don't know what web server you're using, but I personally use [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/).  Your application can have a bunch of its threads be the web server, with however many other threads you like as background tasks.  This way you don't need any kind of complex IPC with sockets, named pipes, etc.  Instead you simply access shared, global, synchronized data structures to pass along information, and your different modules can directly call each others functions.

EDIT: To clarify, you can use the [threading module](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) to run your CherryPy server in different threads than your other blocking servers.  For example:

```
def listener():
    sock = get_socket_from_somewhere()
    while True:
        client, addr = sock.accept()
        # send data back to client, etc

from threading import Thread
t1 = Thread(target=listener)
t1.setDaemon(True)
t1.start()

cherrypy.quickstart() # you'd need actual arguments here
```

This example shows how to have a blocking server in one thread in the same process as a web server (in this case CherryPy, though it could be anything).

Comment: Is it possible to implement a background task which is a blocking call in the same process with CherryPy? In fact my background task is a server that would be listening to a port. I guess the whole thing can be seen as two servers interacting with each other.